# How to invoke my lambda function on every email in my sqs one at a time

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a lambda function that will pull my dynamo table and then push data to salesforce that works fine, what we need to have happen now since the lambda function is limited to 5 min is to have it pull from sqs an email (or client id one at a time and run the lambda function once per each email in order to not have it run over its limit.We have tried a few ways such as loops and a few other ways my team mate tried.

```
 function receive() {
  var aws = require('aws-sdk');
  var sqs = new aws.SQS({"region": "us-west-2"});
  var params = {
   QueueUrl: "https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/*****/****",
  MaxNumberOfMessages: 1
  };
  sqs.receiveMessage(params, function(err, data) {
// var message = JSON.load(data['Message'])
// var message = JSON.load(data);
// var message = data;
    var message = data.Messages[0],
    body = JSON.parse(message.Body);
    console.log(body.client_id);

    get_client_from_dynamo(body.client_id);

    // console.log("Raw" + data)
  });
}
```

This way here will work but only will invoke the lambda function for the last email on the list. Any suggestions would help, as I am still somewhat new to salesforce and the lambda thing as well although I have learned a good bit in the last few weeks which I love. I will include more code if needed.

Comment: If lambda cannot finish the processing within 5 minutes, go check whether it is cause by slow processing or data throughput limit. If due to slow processing, you can try provision up to 1.5GB  RAM.

Answer (score 2):

If your AWS Lambda function is taking longer than 5 minutes to execute, then your task is probably **not appropriate for Lambda**.

AWS Lambda is ideal for situations where some work is **triggered** by an event, such as new information arriving.

Alternatively, you could trigger Lambda to **process a smaller chunk of work**. For example, run a Lambda function that scans DynamoDB for data to copy, then directly trigger multiple Lambda functions, each doing a small piece of work. You can fire off hundreds or even thousands of Lambda functions, each doing a small task.

You could also consider using a small `t2` instance (eg `t2.nano`), which is under 1c/hour or even lower cost as a Reserved Instance. All, you could use an old `t1.micro` instance that's around half a cent per hour under Spot pricing.

Comment: It is not taking longer then that for one or two accounts but if i were to send out the data to all accounts in sales force that i have in my dynamo table at once it would take far to long. It also does not depend on new data arriving to trigger it is a daily event that scans my table and sends out the new days data. I can not use separate lambdas as i do not know when a client will add a new account in to the table using the admin page we created. This was also basically told how i was to do it , just not how to as the bosses want me to try and figure it out without their help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to setup as such that lambda is invoked from SQS, not lambda to go fetch SQS.

this one seems to have a good example
https://cloudonaut.io/integrate-sqs-and-lambda-serverless-architecture-for-asynchronous-workloads/

Dynamo->lambda -> SQS/SNS-> Lambda -> Email/SES